# Why is video.readyState always 1 in the onseeking event?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm building a video player and I want a loader to be shown whenever the video is paused and the user seeks to a certain time in the video that's not yet buffered.

The [`waiting`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-waiting) event only works if the video isn't paused, so it wouldn't work for me in this particular case.

So, to work around this limitation of the [`waiting`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-waiting) event I've attached an event handler to the [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) event, which fires whenever [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) changes manually, that is to say whenever "seeking" starts to happen, and in that event handler I'm checking the video's [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) property to see if the new place in the video that the user has seeked to is ready to be played or not.

But the problem is that [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is always 1 in the event handler of the [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) event no matter what, even if the area that you seek to is actually completely buffered and can be played.

In the snippet below, do the following:

1. Pause the video.
2. Seek to a time in the video that's not buffered.
3. The [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) event fires and [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is 1, which means that point in the video is not yet downloaded.
4. Now, seek back to an area that's already buffered.
5. The [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeking_event) event fires again, but [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is STILL 1, but expectedly it should be >= 2 because that area is buffered. Why is that?!
   [image]

```js
const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

video.addEventListener('waiting', () => {
  console.log('waiting FIRED');
});

video.addEventListener('seeking', () => {
  console.log('seeking FIRED');
  console.log('seeking FIRED | currentTime:', video.currentTime);
  console.log('seeking FIRED | readyState:', video.readyState);
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
```

I also can't use the [`seeked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeked_event) event because it fires after the new area that the user has seemed to is buffered, which defeats the whole purpose of what I'm trying to achieve in the first place. I want to be noticed when the user seeks to a new point in the video **before** that point is buffered, so that I can show a loader or something.

Answer (score 1):

Since the full video is not buffered, a `readyState` of `1` sounds correct.

Remember that seeking is async, (even though the `.currentTime` value is updated synchronously, it doesn't represent the "current playback position"). So when the *seeking* event fires, the browser already left the current position but didn't yet "*set the current playback position to the new playback position*" nor "*established whether or not the media data for the new playback position is available*". ([specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#seeking))
So at this time it can't tell if it has any data at the **will-be** *current playback position*, and all it can say is that it has some metadata.

But for what you are trying to do, you'd be better using the [`HTMLMediaElement.buffered`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered) property, which returns a TimeRanges object representing the time-ranges already buffered.

```js
const video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
video.addEventListener('seeking', () => {
  const buffered = video.buffered;
  let buffering = true;
  // loop through all ranges
  for ( let i = 0; i < buffered.length; i++ ) {
    const start = buffered.start(i);
    const end = buffered.end(i);
    // note that currentTime returns the "official playback position", not the "current playback position"
    // its value is set synchronously
    if( start <= video.currentTime && end >= video.currentTime ) {
      buffering = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log('buffering:', buffering);
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
```

Comment: `Since the full video is not buffered, a readyState of 1 sounds correct.` That's not actually true. `readyState` isn't about the entire video, it's about the current playback position. If you look at [this property's page in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState), for the value `2`, for example, it says "Data is available for the **current playback position**". Furthermore, if you actually pause the video on a buffered area, and then go to the console manually and check the video's `readyState`, you'll see it's actually >= 2, as expected.

Comment: Yes but you are in the seeking event. At this moment the player already left the current position but doesn't know if it will have enough once the seeking is done. So 1 sounds correct.